# Why are the Ajax requests being called twice?

Tags: struts2, dojo

I have a problem regarding Struts2, Ajax.

I added a few a days ago an interceptor to my project to verify that the user is logged in whenever he/she makes a request. Later, i noticed that most of the requests in my project were being called twice.

After some debbuging, I noticed that it probably had to do with the Ajax tags (Dojo) i was using.

I notice that everytime an ajax request that used the < sx > tag, the request was called twice. Like here:

```
<s:form action='crear_proyecto'>
        <div><s:textfield id="jefe_proyecto_text" label="Jefe de proyecto"/></div>

        <s:url id="elegir_usuario_url" value="/buscar_usuarios.action">
            ...
        </s:url>

        <sx:bind sources="jefe_proyecto_text" events="onfocus" targets="buscar_usuarios_dialog" href="%{elegir_usuario_url}"/>
        <sx:submit id="crear_proyecto_submit" targets="ventana_mensaje_proyecto" value="Crear proyecto"/>
    </s:form>
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check what is your main page header consists ?

like suppose it should have mandatory as `<%@ taglib prefix="sx" uri="/struts-dojo-tags"%>`

along with this it should have this

```
<sx:head debug="false" cache="false" compressed="false" parseContent="true" />
```

parseContent should be 'true' -- if it is false then it will submit record twice it seems.